# Running NGINX as a Reverse Proxy on Docker?

Tags: nginx, docker

I'm trying to run nginx as a reverse proxy for Gogs using Docker.  First I setup gogs and I can see a web page for it rendered on:

http://203.0.113.1:3000/

But I want to have NGINX proxy it for me such that I can leave the port (3000) off the URL.  The instructions I'm following come from the NGINX section of this tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-gogs-on-ubuntu-14-04

In order to get this working with docker I created a nginx-data volume, and placed the nginx configuration file in that volume naming it `gogs`.  My configuration file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 203.0.113.2;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr; # pass on real client IP

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://203.0.113.1:3000;
    }
}
```

And it's located at the root of the `nginx-data` volume.  I start the nginx container like this:

```
docker run --name docker-nginx -p 80:80 --net mk1net --ip 203.0.113.2 -v nginx-data:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ -d nginx
```

Now when I visit `203.0.113.2` I'm expecting to see the Gogs page, but I'm just getting the "Welcome to NGINX" page.

Thoughts?

TIA,

Ole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer:

Place the proxy configuration in a file named `gogs.conf` within the docker volume and map it like this:

```
docker run --name docker-nginx -p 80:80 --net mk1net --ip 203.0.113.2 -v nginx-data:/etc/nginx/conf.d/ -d nginx
```

### Explanation:

To see how nginx is configured on a default Ubuntu install I installed it `sudo apt-get install nginx` and took a look at the configuration file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.  It includes these two lines at the bottom of the configuration:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

So I compared that to the nginx configuration of the docker container:

```
docker run --rm -it nginx /bin/ash
root@9475f1693539: cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

This configuration only has this line:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

Hence the configuration from `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` is not included.